# how to pass value from commit to GitLab CI pipeline as variable?

Tags: variables, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I need to dynamically pass value to GitLab CI pipeline to pass the value further to jobs. The problem is: the value cannot be stored in the code and no pipeline reconfiguration should be needed (e.g. I can pass the value in "variables" section of `.gitlab-ci.yml` but it means store value in the code, or changes in "Environment variables" section of "CI / CD Settings" means manual reconfiguration). Also, branch name cannot be used for that purpose too.

It is not a secret string but a keyword which modifies pipeline execution.
So, how can I do it?

Comment: If you are able to find anything to help with the above issue please update the question with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the source of this value.

You say "pass value from commit to ..."
If it's some meta information about the commit itself, look at the list of [Predefined environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)
There's quite a lot of vars named `CI_COMMIT_*` which might work for you.

However,
if it's some value that you generate in the pipeline **in one job** and want to pass to **another job** - it's a different case.
There is a long-living request to [Pass variables between jobs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/47517), which is still not implemented.

The workaround for this moment is to use **artifacts** - files to pass information between jobs in stages.
Our use case is to extract Java app version from `pom.xml` and pass it to some packaging job later.
Here is how we do it in our `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
...
variables:
  VARIABLES_FILE: ./variables.txt  # "." is required for image that have sh not bash

...

get-version:
  stage: prepare
  image: ...
  script:
    - APP_VERSION=...
    - echo "export APP_VERSION=$APP_VERSION" > $VARIABLES_FILE
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $VARIABLES_FILE
...
package:
  stage: package
  image: ...
  script:
    - source $VARIABLES_FILE
    - echo "Use env var APP_VERSION here as you like ..."
```

Comment: No, it is not between jobs but during commit. Source - I thought about tagging of the branches but I didn't find a way to check tag content (not its presence). It can be an env variable on the developer's side or a git command parameter or anything like that - but it should not be committed to the repo.

Comment: @Putnik the solution is working to pass any text to next stage(s)