# Is it possible to use dynamic variables in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

For example, I want to store some results from API call:

```
variables:
  DYNAMIC_VAR: $(curl http://ifconfig.me)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you cannot do this.

If you only need to use this var in a single job, then it's simple:

```
job:
  script:
    - DYNAMIC_VAR=$(curl http://ifconfig.me)
    - echo "Using $DYNAMIC_VAR here ..."
```

However if you need to pass this var between jobs, at the moment it's not directly possible, but you can do it via artifacts.
See example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56818718/902415

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Artifact or Cache if you have to use this information in other jobs otherwise above answer is the perfect solution.